# Jest.js test doesn't work with Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a Jest test that checks the value of the input field containing currency. The number is formatted using **global.Intl.NumberFormat** like so:

```
const formatter = new global.Intl.NumberFormat(locale, config);
```

Where **locale** is set to **nl-NL** and config is

```
{ style: 'decimal',
  currency: 'EUR',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2 }
```

When I simulate input in my test, I get the US formatting for the number, even though in my browser it works just fine. 
For example, if I do

```
input.simulate('change', { target: { value: '5000' } });
```

I would get '5,000.00' formatting, where for Euro I should get '5.000,00'.
It does the formatting, but not for the right locale. 
I wonder if Jest is mocking something for me and if so how can I turn this off? Any clues would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you're using Karma or PhantomJS in your test set up, you might need to patch Intl support with something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-intl-shim ?

Comment: I'm using enzyme, so looks like I can use enzyme-react-intl if I use react-intl for globalization. I will look into doing it that way. Thank you for the pointer!

Answer (score 4):

You need to install https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-icu to include all locales in Node or Test environments. In browser all locales are included but in Node only english is loaded by default.

More info: https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html.

With the package installed adjust your **package.json** scripts:

`"test": "NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu jest"`

You might also need to change scripts executed by node with `node --icu-data-dir=node_modules/full-icu file`, otherwise *NumberFormat* might behave differently on client and server.

Comment: that's the one that worked for me! Also, added `--save-dev` when installing `full-icu`