# Jest Test Currency Format

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

So I am trying to write some unit tests to make sure my currency and number for matter works. I am not understanding why its having issues. Not sure what I am doing wrong

[image]

Here is the code I have in test

```
test('currency for spanish language', () => {
  const value = formatCurrency({
    currency_code: '',
    value: 10,
  },'es_ES');

  expect(value).toContain('10 US$');
});
```

Here is the function:

```
  return new Intl.NumberFormat(lang, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: item.currency_code !== '' ? item.currency_code : 'USD',
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  }).format(item.value);
```

Comment: Can you add the `formatCurrency` function code?

Comment: Done, added to OP

Comment: Try to write expect(value).toContain('10 $US'); instead of expect(value).toContain('10 US$');

Comment: It looks like either the formatted function or the expected value has bad formatting when I look at the expected result vs the toContain() clause.  

Also, maybe the type is different.

Comment: It’s not liking the space it seems

Comment: Looks like this behavior occurs because jest doesn't ship the full internationalization support by default. If you try with `'en-US'` will work perfectly. There's already others questions in SO and you can take some solutions from - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052731/jest-test-intl-datetimeformat/50119588), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52329629/intl-numberformat-behaves-incorrectly-in-jest-unit-test) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098641/jest-js-test-doesnt-work-with-intl-numberformat)

Answer (score 2):

look here:
https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/376

```
test('currency for spanish language', () => {
  const value = formatCurrency({
    currency_code: '',
    value: 10,
  },'es_ES');

  expect(value).toHaveTextContent(value.replace(/\u00a0/g, ' '));
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).